# 3 Phase generator 300v

Tags: generator

I've just been looking at purchasing a 3 phase generator for powering wood working machines in the UK. However while I have been looking I have come across generators which only have a voltage gauge which go up to 300V and some 3 phase generators outputting 220V. I always thought 3 phase had to be 415V which my machines say they require. Could anyone explain to me what these generators are for and are they appropriate for my needs?

Such as the one shown here: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/DEUTZ-Generator-100-KVA-3-Phase-200-volts-/121873808599?hash=item1c603ebcd7:g:suQAAOSwqYBWo8WG

Comment: Which generators? Link, photos, datasheets, man. Ask a good question. Capital V for volts when abbreviated. Welcome to SE!

Comment: 3 phase voltage could be measured between phases, or phase-to-neutral.  With the normal UK single phase (or phase-to-neutral) 240 V, the phase-to-phase voltage will be 415 V.

Comment: It's hard to know what that generator is. The spec is too vague. It could be designed to generate a North American equipment compatible supply.

Comment: To see the full spec you need to scroll to the photo of the nameplate, select it and mouse over it to magnify it.

Answer (score 3):

The generator that you linked has 200 V, 400 Hz, 3-phase output. It is probably intended for use at an airport to supply electrical power to aircraft when their engines are not running. It is not suitable for supplying power to equipment that requires UK mains power.

A 220 V, 3-phase, 50 Hz generator is suitable for powering a 380 V, 3-phase, 50 Hz, star connected motor that is reconnected delta. A 240 V, 3-phase, 50 Hz generator is suitable for powering a 415 V, 3-phase, 50 Hz, star-connected motor that is reconnected delta.

Comment: yup, thats a groundcart :)